# Express JS serve react js files

Tags: reactjs, express

I have an express js backend and a react js frontend.
Now i want to serve this as one project.

Is it possible to build a task with webpack, grunt etc. to build the react js first and then move the build to the public folder in express js?

Answer (score 0):

There is! You can serve your static client files (your react app) from your server.  I would suggest checking out this article if you want to know how to do so https://originmaster.com/running-create-react-app-and-express-crae-on-heroku-c39a39fe7851

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You need to make a production build which will place all files in a directory; let's say "dist" directory. Now you can run express server or any other server (lite-server suggested) and set base directory as "dist" which will run index.html by default and your app will be running in production mode.

You can read official article from Facebook here :

https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html